# How to import all dependencies of a .jar?

Tags: java, android, apache, maven

I'm porting [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) to Android.

Until now I've imported the repositories [`flink:flink-streaming-java_2.10`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java_2.10/1.0.0) and [`flink:flink-clients_2.10`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-clients_2.10/1.0.0-hadoop1) using maven, adding to my `build.gradle` the f:

```
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.10:1.0.0-hadoop1'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.10:1.0.0-hadoop1'
```

Now I have to modify one of the [`flink-runtime_2.10`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-runtime_2.10/1.0.0-hadoop1), in particular `Flink/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/instance/InstanceManager.java`.

So how do you suggest me to do it? I could modify [Flink's src code](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/flink/flink-1.0.0/flink-1.0.0-src.tgz) and then include the `.jar` generated by Maven, but this is "dangerous" operation the I would avoid (the version of Maven's repository could be different from the src code one) and then I should import manually all the dependencies that `flink-runtime` relies on, right?

For example since `flink-runtime` relies on `Scopt`, then I have to add to the `build.gradle` file the following instruction:

`compile 'com.github.scopt:scopt_2.10:3.4.0'`

Right? This is a pain, since `flink-runtime` relies on SO MANY other libraries.

There is any simpler/safer/quicker solution?

Comment: What's your plan going forward? Suppose in future, Flink updates version, you either then have to re-apply your mod(s) or stay on older version.

Comment: Modifying a library source isn't dangerous, it's just tedious because now you have to keep your modifications up to date. Clone the flink source code, change the groupID and version, and then make your changes. Then you just add a dependency your new version of flink instead of apache's version. That said, I generally recommend avoiding library modifications like that at all costs unless there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know what you mean, but there is no way that porting such a big project to Android will not require ANY kind of modification. So I agree with you about the disadvantage of keeping the library updated, but I don't think that there is any other way.